# Find the probability that the third sword appears in the sixth extraction

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

**From a deck of playing cards, several cards are successively selected randomly and without replacement. Find the
probability that the third sword appears in the sixth extraction.**

*Define*

Let $A$: Event of obtaining two swords in the first five selected cards

$B$: The event of a sword in the sixth extraction.

The probability to find is: $P(A\bigcap B)$.

I know how to calculate $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ but I do not know how I can do to calculate $P(A\bigcap B)$, I think you have to use conditional probability, could someone help me please?

I believe that $P(A)=4\frac{\frac{4!}{2!2!}\frac{48!}{46!2!}}{\frac{52!}{50!}}$ and $P(B)=(\frac{48}{52})^5\frac{4}{52}$, am I right? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is a sword card?

Comment: Please describe the deck.  How many sword cards are there?

Comment: Is this a Tarot deck?  If so, there are $78$ cards, of which $10$ are Swords.  See [this](http://starpathways.com/tarot/structure-of-the-tarot/) for example.  But, really, why make your readers guess what you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by Sword Card you mean Jack, then

> I know how to calculate $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ but I do not know how I can do to calculate $P(A\cap B)$, I think you have to use conditional probability, could someone help me please?

- $A\cap B$ is the event of obtaining *two* from *four* 'swords' and *three* from *fourty-eight* non-swords, when selecting any *five* from all *fifty-two* cards without replacement, **and** obtaining the *one* of the remaining *two* swords when drawing any *one* from the remaining *fourty-seven* cards.
- It is also the event that shuffling will place: *two* sword in the first *five* places, *one* in the next place, and *one* among the remaining *fourty six* places;  when the shuffle selects places for the *four* swords in the deck of *fifty-two* cards.

> I believe that $P(A)=4\frac{\frac{4!}{2!2!}\frac{48!}{46!2!}}{\frac{52!}{50!}}$ and $P(B)=(\frac{48}{52})^5\frac{4}{52}$, am I right?

No.   You are aiming at the right place, but are a little off the mark.

- $A$ is the event of obtaining *two* from *four* 'swords' and *three* from *fourty-eight* non-swords, when selecting any *five* from all *fifty-two* cards without replacement.
- It is also the event that shuffling will place *two* swords in the first *five* places and *two* in the remaining *fourty-seven* places, when the shuffle selects places for the *four* swords in the deck of *fifty-two*.
  $$\mathsf P(A)=\dfrac{\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{48}{3}}{\dbinom{52}5}=\cfrac{\cfrac{4!}{2!~2!}\cfrac{48!}{3!~45!}}{\cfrac{52!}{5!~47!}} =\cfrac{\cfrac{5!}{2!~3!}\cfrac{47!}{2!~45!}}{\cfrac{52!}{4!~48!}} =\dfrac{\dbinom 52\dbinom{47}2}{\dbinom{52}4}$$
- $B$ is the event of obtaining *one* from *four* swords when selecting *one* from *fifty-two* cards for the sixth draw.

$$\mathsf P(B)=\dfrac{\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{52}{1}}$$

- Now, $A$ and $B$ are not independent, so you will have to use conditional probability, or calculate using the suggestion above.